# How to show choices fields in django admin?

Tags: django

I have a model with a lot of fields, Some fields are Char type with choices
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices

These fields don't display in the admin panel

list_display I generate like this

```
list_display = [field.name for field in Event._meta.get_fields()]
```

How to change the generation of the list, so that fields with type choices are shown ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list choices on you model like this :

On the top of your models.py declare this:

```
SAMPLE_LIST = ((1, 'LIST 1'),
                (2, 'LIST 2'),
                (3, 'LIST 3'),
                (4, 'LIST 4'))
```

Then on your model class, you can use it like this :

```
class tblWhatever(models.Model):
    LIST_FIELD = MultiSelectField(choices=SAMPLE_LIST ,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.LIST_FIELD)
```